# Multiple row results when selecting with join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select a user's name to go with my other data, but I keep getting multiple rows with my SELECT query.

Name field is broken, but the others work fine.

Struckture goes as follows- user has work_detail_id and shift_worker has work_detail_id. I need the name of user that has the same work_detail_id as the shift_worker (shift_worker > work_detail > user).

How would I fix this?

```
    SELECT
  (SELECT name
   FROM user_acc
   JOIN shift_worker ON user_acc.work_detail_id = shift_worker.work_detail_id
   WHERE user_acc.work_detail_id = shift_worker.work_detail_id
   GROUP BY user_acc.name) AS name,
       count(sw.id) AS shift_count,
       sum(sw.actual_work_duration) AS work_duration,
       sum(sw.actual_shift_duration) AS shift_duration
FROM shift_worker sw
JOIN work_detail wd ON sw.work_detail_id = wd.id
WHERE sw.work_detail_id = wd.id
  AND sw.actual_work_start_time > '2019-10-01 00:00:00'
  AND sw.actual_work_start_time < '2019-10-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY wd.id
```

Comment: Please post a data set and your wished result set

Comment: @JoeTaras user_acc has name field and work_detail_id field. work_detail_id has a one-to-one relationship with user_acc which contains various information that I don't need for this query. shift_worker contains information about the shift and a work_detail_id field. My wished result set is to have all shift_workers grouped by work_detail_id and show name, shift_worker count, work_duration and shift_duration :)

Comment: Hi, please post a sample about data set (for each table put few rows in this question) and then put the wished result set. So the logic can be more clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 2 -

```
SELECT
    max(ua.name) as name,
    count(sw.id) as shift_count,
    sum(sw.actual_work_duration) as work_duration,
    sum(sw.actual_shift_duration) as shift_duration
FROM shift_worker sw
JOIN user_acc ua ON ua.work_detail_id = sw.work_detail_id
JOIN work_detail wd ON sw.work_detail_id = wd.id
WHERE sw.work_detail_id = wd.id AND
    sw.actual_work_start_time > '2019-10-01 00:00:00' AND
    sw.actual_work_start_time < '2019-10-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY wd.id
```

Try 1-

I think you need `co-related query` instead of `sub-query`. I have removed extra `join` with `shift_worker` table from `sub-query`. Please try this-

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT name 
        FROM user_acc
        WHERE user_acc.work_detail_id = sw.work_detail_id 
        GROUP BY user_acc.name
    ) as name, 
    count(sw.id) as shift_count, 
    sum(sw.actual_work_duration) as work_duration, 
    sum(sw.actual_shift_duration) as shift_duration  
FROM shift_worker sw 
JOIN work_detail wd ON sw.work_detail_id = wd.id 
WHERE sw.work_detail_id = wd.id AND 
    sw.actual_work_start_time > '2019-10-01 00:00:00' AND 
    sw.actual_work_start_time < '2019-10-31 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY wd.id
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now: ERROR:  subquery uses ungrouped column "sw.work_detail_id" from outer query

Answer (score 1):

Your query is a mess.  For instance, it repeats conditions in the `on` clause and the `where` clause.  It is using subqueries unnecessarily.

I think you want:

```
SELECT ua.name as name,
       count(*) as shift_count,
       sum(sw.actual_work_duration) as work_duration,
       sum(sw.actual_shift_duration) as shift_duration
FROM shift_worker sw JOIN
     user_acc ua
     ON ua.work_detail_id = sw.work_detail_id JOIN
     work_detail wd
     ON sw.work_detail_id = wd.id
WHERE sw.actual_work_start_time > '2019-10-01' AND
      sw.actual_work_start_time < '2019-10-31'
GROUP BY sw.id, ua.name;
```

I also suspect that you want the entire month of October.  If so:

```
WHERE sw.actual_work_start_time >= '2019-10-01' AND
      sw.actual_work_start_time < '2019-11-01'
```